# Launch multiple stored procedures to run 'in the background' on SQL Server Express Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server, concurrency, background, sql-server-express

Is it possible to run multiple stored procedures that run 'in the background'?

The stored procedures **must be launched from a single, master stored procedure**, in the same way that multiple worker threads are spawned.  For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyLauncher
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN
      @EXEC MyBackgroundSP01 -- Runs in parallel to the other 2
      @EXEC MyBackgroundSP02 -- Runs in parallel to the other 2
      @EXEC MyBackgroundSP03 -- Runs in parallel to the other 2
    END
END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible in SQL 2005 and later. Have look at http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/

Answer (score 2):

No this isn't possible as you have described it. You could run multiple SQL Jobs which will execute the procedures concurrently/

Comment: The procedure has to run on MS SQL Express Edition, so Jobs can't be 
used.  I'll amend the question to mention this.

Comment: Whats calling the procedure? Why not have the caller handle the threading?

Comment: SQL Server is calling the procedure on startup.  I can always work around this by getting SQL Server to call the procedures individually but I thought I would check to see if there was a more elegant way.

I have a feeling I'm trying to do something that would break the ACID principles for transactions 8)

Comment: It is possible with Express using straight T-SQL: http://rusanu.com/2009/08/05/asynchronous-procedure-execution/

Answer (score 0):

According to this question you could try using the Service Broker

[Asynchronous Stored Procedure Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460/asynchronous-stored-procedure-calls)

Answer (score 0):

If you run they in the same procedure, it will launch in the same thread (and in the same internal transaction, what can make the log very big).

Answer (score 0):

Not with pure T-SQL. But you could write a little dotNET app to run them asynchronously easily enough, as long as you leave the connection option until all three are finished.

Answer (score 0):

IF both Stored procedure have same parameter then you can create a new store procedure
like

```
create third procedure
(@colname int)
as
 begin

exec first procedure
exec second procedure
end

exec third procedure
```

You can try it. I am sure how appropriate it is.