# Stored procedure executing another stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When a Stored Procedure has a query inside to execute another Stored Procedure, does the calling Stored Procedure stop other Stored Procedure has finished executing?  I guess I'm trying to get straight in my head whether it's like synchronous and asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes they are synchronous.  They would have to be.   If stored procedure A is expecting a result from stored procedure B, then it would have to wait for Stored Procedure B to finish.  The implications would be huge if they were automatically asynchronous.

For a follow up.  Here is how to make stored procedures asynchronous in MSSQL Server (well as asynchronous as possible):

[Asynchronous Stored Procedure Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25460/asynchronous-stored-procedure-calls)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's synchronous

Comment: That's great.  Makes sense after reading Kevin's answer as well.